# Laravel foreach to retrive user IDs

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel project i has model Promo, where located only `user_id` column.
I have 2 records in this Model.
I need to retrive all `user_id`'s from Promo model.

First i take all user_id's from Model:

`$userList = Promo::get();`

`dd` say me, that i has 2 records:

[image]

This true result, than i try to make foreach:

```
        foreach ($userList as $userIds) {
            $userIds = $userIds->user_id;
        }
```

And if i use `var_dump` or `dd`, it's always show to me 1 user_id, but i has 2 user_id in table.

Where can be mistake?

Comment: Don't use a `foreach()` to get that, just do `$userIds = $userList->pluck('user_id')`. But, for your issue, if you're setting the same variable multiple times in a Loop, only the last time it is set will be kept. You're basically writing `$userIds = 1;` then `$userIds = 2`, so of course it will only be `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the value of `$userIds` each time the loop count and the final value is the last value of the `$userList`.
You can do it in 2 different ways:

with the loop:

```
$userList = Promo::get();
$userIds = [];

foreach ($userList as $user) {
    $userIds[] = $user->user_id;
}
```

or with the [Laravel collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-pluck) `pluck()` (**recommended**):

```
$userIds = Promo::pluck('user_id');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting `$userIds` each time. There's an [easier way](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-pluck) to get just the user Ids

```
$userIds = $userList->pluck('user_id')->all();
```

This will return an array of user_ids from your userList collection.

Comment: And if you want a `Collection` instead of an `Array`, drop the `->all()`; depends on intended use case 

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're assigning user id  to $userIds variable. It always returns one value.
Try this,

```php
  $userIdsarray =[] ;
foreach ($userList as $userIds) {
  $userIdsarray[] = $userIds->user_id;
}
```

Comment: This will work if you actually define `$userIdsArray`, which you didn't do